# Android get sms receiver-number from inbox

Tags: android, phone-number

I'm trying to receive the phone number of the device,

but

```
tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

is not reliable

now I'm trying to retrieve the number from the sms in in or sent box

```
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
        Cursor cur = ctx.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);
        String[] columnNames = cur.getColumnNames();
        if (cur.moveToFirst())
            do {
                Log.d("sms reciever",cur.getString(2));

            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        cur.close();
```

but on inbox column 2 is the sender, and in sentbox it is the reciver, any ideas how to retrieve the number of the current phone from the sms?

Comment: you cant, just sms center number is available

Answer (score 1):

This must help you

```
TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
  mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

with READ_PHONE_STATE permission.

And I think there isn't best way to do this. Because this is dependening some conditions... Phone numbers may not stored in sim cards in everywhere, every location. You must ask it user to type his/her number and store it.

Comment: i already wrote in my post "getLine1Number is not reliable" it only works if it is saved on the sim